# Embed with out the value field

Tags: discord, discord.py

How can you have an embeded text field with out all I want it to say is "Total Damage" and then display the image...

I have tried just about every combination of leaving it blank value="" or value=None or leaving off the value but then you get an error saying it is required.

`diceEmbed.add_field(name='Total Damage', value=None)`

[image of the embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbcRS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unicode character for `zero width space`

```py
embed.add_field(name='Total Damage', value='\u200b')
# You can also use it in the name
```

Comment: Consider explaining your code so others can understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually set a value to None so you have to use a unicode as such:

```py
embed.add_field(name="name", value='\u200')
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not the best way of doing this, but it does work for me.

```
diceEmbed.add_field(name='Total Damage', value=** **)
```